# Keep keys order of JSON objects stored in Snowflake ARRAY type field

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have stablished a connection to Snowflake from python, using:

```
import snowflake.connector
params = dict(
            user=<my_user>,
            password=<my_pass>,
            account=<my_acc>,
            warehouse=<my_wh>,
            database=<my_db>,
            schema=<my_schema>
)
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(**params)
```

Then I issue this command:

`ctx.cursor().execute("update <my_wh>.<my_db>.<my_tb> set DICT_FIELD = [{'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}] where ID = 'my_id';")`

What I expect to see in the table under `DICT_FIELD` (of type `ARRAY`) is this:
`[{'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}]`

But I see in practice is this:
`[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}]`

What should I do to keep the JSON keys order as sent?

Versions:

```
python=3.9.7
snowflake-connector-python[pandas]==3.0.3
```

Comment: @roganjosh thanks a lot for that.
As I read there is a discussion about reading the JSON, with a conclusion that order cannot be guaranteed.
Do you think I can conclude that even if I manage to save it in the original order, then there is no way that original order to be kept?

Comment: That would be my conclusion since hashmaps (which is basically what your JSON will become) are often implemented in an unordered way. The chance that this has any impact at all on your code is minimal in my mind - do you have a case where this is an issue?

Comment: Well, we have a case but we can implement a work around knowing that keys won't reflect the original order. I we were to do that with the JSON, then I would use a sorting primary key on top of the original keys.